# Pandas Selecting By Checking Whether List Element Contains value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe that corresponds to lists in rows:

```
                                                   tags  contestId
20              [graphs, greedy, shortest paths, trees]       1437
27                       [binary search, combinatorics]       1436
64    [constructive algorithms, data structures, gre...       1426
81    [binary search, math, number theory, two point...       1423
111   [binary search, brute force, constructive algo...       1419
...                                                 ...        ...
6444                                             [math]         11
6449                               [dp, implementation]         10
6464                                   [implementation]          7
6486                          [hashing, implementation]          2
6488                             [implementation, math]          1
```

How can I select all records that have either 'math' or 'trees' in tags list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
ans = df[df["tags"].apply(lambda el: "math" in el or "trees" in el)]
```

## Output

```
print(ans)
   index                                             tags  contestId
0     20          [graphs, greedy, shortest paths, trees]       1437
3     81  [binary search, math, number theory, two point]       1423
5   6444                                           [math]         11
9   6488                           [implementation, math]          1
```

### Test Data

```
# in.txt

index                                              tags  contestId
20              [graphs, greedy, shortest paths, trees]       1437
27                       [binary search, combinatorics]       1436
64      [constructive algorithms, data structures, gre]       1426
81      [binary search, math, number theory, two point]       1423
111     [binary search, brute force, constructive algo]       1419
6444                                             [math]         11
6449                               [dp, implementation]         10
6464                                   [implementation]          7
6486                          [hashing, implementation]          2
6488                             [implementation, math]          1
```

Code to reconstruct `df` (please provide such code next time):

```
df = pd.read_fwf("in.txt")
df["tags"] = df["tags"].apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(", "))
```

N.B. Unfortunately, `.isin()` and `.str.contains()` did not seem to be working.